# setcors / getcors for individual files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried doing [setcors / getcors](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_reference_guide#setorgetcors) to a single file, but I get

```
CommandException: URI gs://bucket/cat.png must name a bucket for the setcors command
gsutil getcors gs://bucket.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/cat.png
CommandException: "getcors" command must specify a bucket
```

It (setcors / getcors) works for the entire bucket, but the documentation says differently.
Do I need to update my gsutil utility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can only be specified at the bucket level. Do you have a URL for the spot in the docs that says you can set it on individual objects?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_reference_guide#setorgetcors. gsutil setcors my-cors-config.txt gs://cats/mycats.png. gsutil getcors gs://cats/mycats.png